# How to pass the destination value from many message driven channel adapter to common inbound channel in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

Having the following requirement, where we have many message driven channel adapter to consume messages from a  different WMQ's and send it to common outbound channel.

I need the detail of  message adapter that consumes the message to handle the business scenarios.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all no one in the Spring Integration sends directly to the `inbound channel`. Let's hope you mean a common `outbound channel adapter`.

There is not too much out-of-the-box information about a message driven channel adapter in the messages it emits. Maximum what you can do is to enable [Message History](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history) - and the message will have an `id` of components it travels through.

If you need more info, I suggest to place a [Header Enricher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-enricher) just after each message driven channel adapter and populate a required information from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have updated the question accordingly.
Whether creating multiple header enricher for different message driven channel adapter is effective though am going to send it to a common outbound channel ?

Comment: Well, as I said you: there is no other choice. What's wrong with the `header enricher` approach? You are free to populate in the message headers anything you need. You may have though some common logic based on the JMS headers really populated by the JMS Message Driven Channel Adapter. Not sure what is your concern about "effective", but if you need that information according the business requirement. So, what is the choice?

Comment: Also I said that you can use `message history` and using an endpoint `id` from there you can retrieve the Message Driven Channel Adapter object from the application context and do some logic from there.

Comment: The only concern is about the application performance on having additional check for every  message received.

Let me try using message history and see how it suits to our application.

Thanks for your suggestions!!!